# How to force overflow of divs with float:left

Tags: css

I have two divs with float:left inside a container with a fixed width - something like that

```
<div style="width:1100px">
<div id="A" style="float:left; width: 400px"></div>
<div id="B" style="float:left; min-width: 600px"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem. Both internal divs A and B are generated dynamically and div B can exceed 700px. In that case, it goes below div A. I cannot easily change the width of the container, because it is also generated automatically by bootstrap.

I've tried to play with the overflow options, but it didn't work. I could recalculate the width of the container dynamically with jquery based on the total width of divs A and B, but it will be overdo.

What is the easiest way to force div B stay next to div A **regardless of its width**?

Thanks

Comment: Use percentages? e.g. `#A { width: 40%; } #B { width: 60%; }`

Comment: Either that or try to force a `max-width`.

Comment: cannot use percentage. I need the total width of A + B to exceed the width of container (1100px), e.g. 400px + 850px

Comment: Can you absolute position your DIVs? Giving B a left of 400px, so it will always be there?

Comment: The float is strictly necessary? Cant you use `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Just tried your suggestions:
1) inline-block works the same way as float-left (breaks the 2nd div if total width >1100px
2) overflow-x: scroll - no difference
cannot use abs position

Comment: you can exceed the width of the container easily using % as A50% and B80%

Comment: @user2723490: of course, you have to use also `white-space: nowrap` and remove the extra spaces between the div in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like my comment and using akinuri modified fiddle, using percentage and without scroll bar;

```
#container {
    width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: show; /* or hidden if you dont want the scrool bar */
}
#A {
     background: yellow;
     width: 60%;
}
#B {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 60%;  /* width of #A */
     width: 80%;
     background: blue;
}
```

you get

http://jsfiddle.net/TRFmL/1/

EDIT

I think now I have whatyou want:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: show; /* or hidden if you dont want the scrool bar */
}
#A {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 60%;
}
#B {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -40%; // this is the result of 100 - (A+B)
    display:inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but i would try to find some solution without absolute positioning. This is a part of the huge application with dynamically generated charts and grids inside of these divs. Absolute positions would require me to change a lot of things.

Comment: Hey Santiago, I've found a more simple solution - wrap divs A & B into another div with min-width: 1400px. Now it works even if the main container is 1100px. Still you solution is not bad - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is using absolute positioning.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A">a</div>
    <div id="B">b</div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto; /* or hidden if you dont want the scrool bar */
}
#A {
    background: yellow;
    width: 400px;
}
#B {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 400px;  /* width of #A */
    width: 900px;
    background: blue;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TRFmL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline-block` display for the div, then set `white-space` to `nowrap` and remove any white space between the two div.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VMVAb/

Comment: nice one, white-space